# No spaces in Joomla 2.5 Output

Tags: joomla, editor, components, text-rendering

I'm in a pickle. I've designed a Joomla 2.5 site, which I have locally installed. I typically equip my installations with JCE editor for my clients, but at design time, operate in HTML mode. When all the content was in, I decided to test WYSIWYG mode to make sure nothing went awry. Unfortunately, something did. Observe the lack of spaces:

[image]

Very interesting that the problem occurs ONLY when saving from WYSIWYG view.

At first I thought JCE was malfunctioning (although the editor itself continued to show spaces), so I tried reinstalling. Then I tried other editors -- CKEditor and TinyMCE. The same symptoms manifested with them as well.

Trying to isolate the problem, I checked the database after pasting in clean markup in HTML view, and again after saving in WYSIWYG view. This is the result:

[image]

So, based on the database field, it would appear that the process of saving, in either HTML or WYSIWYG view is working properly... But then why is the output being fed to the browser different depending on which method was used to edit?

[image]

So far I've checked entity encoding, CSS (although it's obviously not a CSS issue), and tried installing on another local server. No changes in behavior.

I could really use some suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Z

PS: This is the latest version of Joomla (2.5.6), running on Apache.

Comment: Are you using any template overriding? E.g. your_template/html/com_content/article/default.php.

Comment: No. There are no overrides in place. Just /templates/my_template/index.php

Comment: Try to var_dump($this->item->text) in components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php.

Comment: The text is now preceded by "string(20231)". Other than that, there is no change.

Comment: What about var_dump(substr($this->item->text, 0, 60))? Would like to know if the variable contains the spaces or not..

Comment: It outputs "<h1>M.A.inIntegrativeHealthandHealing</h1><p>This36-credit", which, with a line break between the heading and paragraph, is 59 characters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16055/discussion-between-fnatte-and-shikarnov)

Answer (score 0):

When we typed some text continually this issue was occurred. Actually this was not the issue this problem was solved by using correct css style for that division.

```
<style type="text/css">#divid {width:750px;word-wrap;break-word;"}</style>
```

You have to use this css style for your division . Surely this ll resolve that problem...

Comment: Your CSS caused the text to wrap within the DIV, but the spaces are still absent between the words themselves.